# AWX problems: email notifications and inventory from git

Tags: git, ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

I am having trouble configuring email notifications in AWX. I have created [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApZkZ.png) but it does not work. When making a test [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOzZ6.png) is what I obtain. I have tried changing the file `/etc/tower/settings.py` in awx_task container and in awx_web container but the result is the same. What is missing here?

I also have a doubt regarding inventories from external sources. It seems that once they are uploaded to AWX it is not possible to select just some of those hosts, because the 'ON' button is restricted like it is shown in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgZxi.png). In my case, I have a list of nodes imported from a git repository and I want to run a playbook just in half of them, but I can't do that if I do not change previously the file in the repository, what is really a nuisance. I could create one or more directories to store inventories and playbooks under the Project Base Path and there use git pull to update them, but is there any other option?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Smart inventory is what you may want to look into.
Another way may be to set template to ask for which nodes to run on ' limit ' option.
If you give more examples of what you are trying to achieve, it will be easier to give a more specific answer.

Comment: Your suggestions are helpful, but I still can't achieve exactly what I want, which is the possibility of selecting the nodes of an inventory as if it was imported manually. For example, I have used awx-manage to get one inventory in AWX, and its nodes can be selected like I show here https://i.imgur.com/XGpXGPW.png,

Comment: Sorry for delay, missed your response. When you are running a job from templates you run it against an inventory file and can restrict nodes using limit option. If you can provide a sample inventory file I could illustrate usage.